# How to add listener to text view than call a method on text change . text view is part of the card view

Tags: android, android-cardview

In this code mytest is the text view    in side the  card view

```
 cards item = new cards(dataSnapshot.getKey(), dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString(), mytest, profileImageUrl);




                            rowItems.add(item);
                            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is your difficulty

Comment: trying to update another text view  using value of the mytest text  view  . Difficultly is cannot get the value updated  when new card is in the view. still showing first card view value   .

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question - you should implement TextWatcher like this (Samples in Kotlin):

```
class MyTextWatcher() : TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
        //Do something
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        //Do something
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

And then attach it to required TextView like this:

```
yourTextView.addTextChangedListener(MyTextWatcher)
```

Answer (score 0):

As `TextView` is an immutable field, I think you can't add a *TextChangedListener*.

But, if you want to watch the changes for `EditText`, please have a look at `TextWatcher` : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher